# Different outcomes based on where python is called

Tags: python, import

When I call python from the raw directory, `download.py` works. As below.

[image: no problem]

(Sorry that I slightly changed the name to `downloaddat.py`, but the content didn't change at all.)

But when I call python from the place where I was supposed to, `download.py` doesn't work.
[image: problem]

Behind the scene, I tried every solutions introduced in stackoverflow to solve that import issues, which means that environment variables, system variables, backend things may not be the reason.

I seem this problem is very huge cause this may mean that I could even get different results based on where python is called.

What is the problem and how can I get rid of it?

For case, I included the paths of environment variables and system variables.
[image: environment variables path]

[image: system variables path]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
It appears that your `download.py` file and `PYTHONPATH` are missing some information to find all the required files.  Since you've neglected to include the environment, let alone enough info to reproduce and diagnose the problem, we can only take a few guesses.

Comment: @Prune Wish I could reproduce this situation...I will check `PYTHONPATH`. Thanks.